# Toggling layer visibility

Tags: qgis, layers

I have 7 separate heatmaps representing 7 years of data, all styled the same in QGIS. The shapes of the heatmaps change slightly between the different years and it would be nice to quickly toggle 2016 off and immediately view 2015 without having to take my eyes off the map canvas to click the little boxes in the layers panel.

I could just take a print screen of each layer and paste them into something like powerpoint and use my arrow keys to have the same effect. Is there a faster approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand right, and you want to show only one heatmap at a time, you can

- set up a **group** in the layers dialog,
- drag your heatmap layers into the group
- set the group to **Mutually Exclusive** (right click on group name)

See [this page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog212/#feature-mutually-exclusive-layer-tree-groups). It should be available from QGIS 2.12 onwards. This type of group only lets you show one layer in the group at a time. But you can turn this setting on and off at will

(I recommend learning how to use groups; they make it much easier to work with your project once you have more than a handful of layers)

For keyboard shortcuts to advance through the layers in the group, make sure one of your layers is selected and use

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd>

or

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd>

(there doesn't seem to be a way to loop back from the first to last layers in a group, or the last layer back to the first, though)